# How to measure both CPU and GPU time taken for each line for python code?

Tags: python, time, gpu, cpu

Below code calculates CPU time taken by entire python code. How can I extend this to each line of code and also add GPU time?

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()
# ...
end = timer()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: Do you mean to time profile your code ? I am coming from thinking in terms of `valgrind` for C/C++

Answer (score 2):

You can track CPU time by:

```py
import time

time_collect = list()
start = time.process_time()
# single line code here    
time_collect.append(time.process_time() - start)
# next single code here    
time_collect.append(time.process_time() - start)
# next single code here    
time_collect.append(time.process_time() - start)
# This line will give you the time for every step after which you append the time
steps_time = [time_collect[i+1] - time_collect[i] for i in range(len(time_collect) - 1)]
```

If you have GPU's, you might need [GPUtil](https://github.com/anderskm/gputil) to get the status from the GPU's, I haven't digged their documentation but they have a mention of `time` library support in their `README.md`.